# Pandas: Fill Cells Down Algorithm

Tags: python, pandas

In the example below I need to populate the 'Parent' column as follows: All of the column values would be CISCO except for rows 0 and 7 (should be left blank).

Note that 'CISCO' "is in" the cell below it 'CISCO System' which "is in" the cell below it 'CISCO Systems' etc. in fact..all of the CISCOs start with 'CISCO' so I need to group all of the cells that have the same start together as one entity and label the parent with the starting cell (CISCO).

We have multiple names for the same vendor so I'm trying to map all of those child 'CISCOs' to one parent 'CISCO'

Please note that I have 100,000 rows so the algorithm must be done automatically without manual intervention (i.e. not simply by hard coding parents = 'CISCO')

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['MICROSOFT','CISCO', 'CISCO System', 'CISCO Systems', 'CISCO Systems CANADA', 'CISCO Systems CANADA Corporation', 'CISCO Systems CANADA Corporation Limited', 'IBM'], columns=['Child']) #,[]], columns=['Child', 'Parent'])
df['Parent'] = ''
df
```

I was hoping that there's an elegant solution, preferably without needing loops. Many thanks for your help!

[image]

Required output:

[image]

Comment: You will first have to find the parent company then after that you can use `df['Parent'].fillna(method = "infer")` to fill down the company to values below.

Comment: `str.contains` ? `df.loc[df['Child'].str.contains('CISCO'),'Parent'] = 'Cisco'` ?

Comment: @ShahirAnsari "find the parent company" I know..that's the hard part that I'm trying to figure out! :-)

Comment: @Datanovice thanks but I think you missed the part where it says no hard coding...there are so many cases like this one in the data so it has to be done automatically

Comment: You have to be more clear, you'll have to do some hard coding somewhere, do you have a list of items you want to extract? Also if you find this automatic code let me know

Comment: @Datanovice I've clearly stated that in the question (last paragraph) and in the description (2nd paragraph) and in the title where it says 'algorithm'. The idea is to go through 100,000 rows...automatically identify all the cases where cells are subset of each other (like this example) and name them as the starting cell (CISCO in this case).  The whole idea is to avoid hardcoding...btw I've already figured it out without harcoding but the code is very complex so that's why I was looking for a better solution than mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I've managed to come out with a very elegant and simple solution that words exactly as I want:

```
    import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['MICROSOFT', 'MICROSOFT CORP','CISCO', 'CISCO System', 'CISCO Systems', 'CISCO Systems CANADA', 'CISCO Systems CANADA Corporation', 'CISCO Systems CANADA Corporation Limited', 'IBM', 'Apple','Apple Corp'], columns=['Child'])
df['Parent'] = ''

c, p = df['Child'], df['Parent']
for y in range (1, df.shape[0]): 
    if c.iat[y-1] in c.iat[y]: p.iat[y] = np.nan #identify children
    if str(p.iat[y]) == 'nan' and p.iat[y-1] == '' : p.iat[y-1] = c.iat[y-1] #identify parent

df['Parent'] = df['Parent'].ffill(axis = 0) #fill children
display(df)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Negative voting a solution without explaining why is really unprofessional.

Answer (score 1):

This is a curly one.
My attempt again;

Data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Child':['CANADA MOTOR','CANADA COMPUTERS', 'CANADA COMPUTERS CORPORATION', 'CANADA COMPUTERS CORPORATION LTD', 'CANADA SUPPLIES', 'CANADA SUPPLIES CORPORATION', 'CANADA SUPPLIES CORPORATION LTD', 'IBM','MICROSOFT','CISCO', 'CISCO System', 'CISCO Systems', 'CISCO Systems CANADA', 'CISCO Systems CANADA Corporation', 'CISCO Systems CANADA Corporation Limited', 'IBM']})
```

Extract first name for each Child into `FirstCompanyName`

```
df['FirstCompanyName']=df.Child.str.extract('(^\w+)')
```

Extract First and Second Names for each child into `df2`, drop those without second name and rename columns to `Child` and `SeconCompanyName`

```
df2=df.Child.str.extract('(^((?:\S+\s+){1}\S+).*)', expand=True).dropna()
df2.columns=['Child','SeconCompanyName']
```

Merge the 2 dataframes, replace any `NaNs` and drop unwanted columns

```
   df3= pd.merge(df, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left',suffixes=('', '_New'))
#df3.fillna('', inplace=True)#
df3.drop(columns=['Child_New'], inplace=True)
df3
```

mask where `SeconCompanyName` is null

```
m=df3.SeconCompanyName.isna()
```

Replace `SeconCompanyName` with `FirstCompanyName` while the mask is still on

```
df3.loc[m,'SeconCompanyName']=df3.loc[m,'FirstCompanyName']
df3
```

**Outcome 1**

[image]

If you dont like the above skip the mask and do the following;

```
df3['SeconCompanyName']=np.where(df3.SeconCompanyName.isna(), df3.shift(-1).SeconCompanyName, df3.SeconCompanyName)
df3.fillna('', inplace=True)
df3
```

**Outcome 2**

[image]

Comment: That's a brilliant idea..you're a genius!!! The only problem in that solution is the one word assumption. It should be the first cell value (whatever it is). Take this example: CANADA MOTORS and CANADA COMPUTERS...your code will call both of them CANADA when it should not. Kindly apply the solution to this df and you'll get what I mean ```df = pd.DataFrame(['CANADA MOTOR','CANADA COMPUTERS', 'CANADA COMPUTERS CORPORATION', 'CANADA COMPUTERS CORPORATION LTD', 'CANADA SUPPLIES', 'CANADA SUPPLIES CORPORATION', 'CANADA SUPPLIES CORPORATION LTD', 'IBM'], columns=['Child'])
df['Parent'] = '' ```

Comment: I was wondering if your solution could be combined with re.findall to cater for the entire cell value instead of the first word only?

Comment: Hopefully, last edit. Please see the edit and revert

Comment: How did you go? Keen to know and support

Comment: Thanks so much! Just saw your post...will test and get back to you soon :-)

Comment: Yup that worked but you're right...it's becoming incredibly complicated. I have done it previously using a while loop across all rows...basically compare every 2 cells and use .iat to update the parent...but it was tricky too. Longer but much simpler. But I'm really grateful for your support and I'm marking it your solution an accepted answer as you've put a lot of effort and it works :-) Thanks so much!

Comment: Happy to hear, all the best

Answer (score 1):

You could split each `Child` column by its white space and take the top n occurances as your pattern to extract using `str.extractall`

Naturally, you'll need to tweak the logic to your use-case.

```
s = df['Child'].str.split(' ',expand=True).stack().value_counts()

pat = '|'.join(s[s.gt(2)].index)

print(pat)
#'CISCO|Systems|CANADA'

df['Parent?'] = df['Child'].str.extractall(f'({pat})').groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
```

---

```
print(df)

                                      Child Parent               Parent?
0                                 MICROSOFT                          NaN
1                                     CISCO                        CISCO
2                              CISCO System                        CISCO
3                             CISCO Systems                CISCO,Systems
4                      CISCO Systems CANADA         CISCO,Systems,CANADA
5          CISCO Systems CANADA Corporation         CISCO,Systems,CANADA
6  CISCO Systems CANADA Corporation Limited         CISCO,Systems,CANADA
7                                       IBM                          NaN
```

Comment: Thanks that's helpful but you're right...it needs to be tweaked to work. I've appreciated the help

Comment: @ShadyMBA no worries, it's a difficult problem with one shot, but I think you could adapt this to get to a pretty ideal scenario.